# open mutiple directories using same for loop in shell

Tags: bash, shell, sh

```
folder_name=(MI IG Chi-square)
for m in {0..2}
do
    folder=${folder_name[$m]}
    echo
    echo  $folder
    echo
    train_path="/home/user/Thesis/DVD/Features/Training/POSITIVE/$folder/Unigram/"
    test_path="/home/user/Thesis/DVD/Features/Testing/POSITIVE/$folder/"
    for f,k in $train_path $test_path 
    do
       if $f in *.arff and $k in *.arff ; then
      echo $f,$k
    done
done
```

this is the code to open two dir such as train_path and $test_path and i want to extract all arff files from these path simultenously.I could solve this problem?any body can help?

Answer (score 1):

Using Bash 4, perhaps something like

```
shopt -s nullglob
base=/home/user/Thesis/DVD/Features
printf '%s\n' "$base/"{Training,Testing}/POSITIVE/{MI,IG,Chi-square}/{Unigram,}/*.arff |
  xargs -P2 extract {}
```

if `extract` is a command to extract arff files. You can also use GNU parallel for this, with the same arguments.

Comment: i want extract the files in these directories also??